# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Predict, value = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, : replacement has 3500 rows, data has 1500

Tags: r, random-forest, supervised-learning

Good Day

I have run a Random Forest with tuning and have added the prediction to the Train data which ran perfectly well and had no issues. However when I tried running the random forest model on the Test dataset I get the above error. Any idea as to what could be causing this below is my code. Appreciate any help with this. The Train dataset does have 3500 rows and the Test would have 1500 rows as the dataset is made of 5000 rows.

R CODE:

```
####Clearing the global environmnent
rm(list = ls())

##Setting the working directory
setwd("D:/Great Learning/Module 3 -Machine Learning/Project")


##Packages required to be loaded
install.packages("DataExplorer")
install.packages("xlsx")
##install.packages("magrittr")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("mice")
install.packages("NbClust")

##Reading in the dataset
library(xlsx)
LoanModelRaw = read.xlsx("Thera Bank_Personal_Loan_Modelling-dataset- 1.xlsx",sheetName = "Bank_Personal_Loan_Modelling",header = T)
##LoanModelRaw = read.csv("Thera Bank_Personal_Loan_Modelling-dataset-1.csv", sep = ";",header = T)

##Viewing the dataset in R
View(LoanModelRaw)
dim(LoanModelRaw)
colnames(LoanModelRaw)
str(LoanModelRaw)
summary(LoanModelRaw)
nrow(LoanModelRaw)
attach(LoanModelRaw)

#Correcting column names
names(LoanModelRaw)[2] = "AgeInYears" 
names(LoanModelRaw)[3] = "ExperienceInYears"
names(LoanModelRaw)[4] = "IncomeInKMonth"
names(LoanModelRaw)[5] = "ZIPCode"
names(LoanModelRaw)[6] = "FamilyMembers"
names(LoanModelRaw)[10] = "PersonalLoan"
names(LoanModelRaw)[11] = "SecuritiesAccount"
names(LoanModelRaw)[12] = "CDAccount" 

colnames(LoanModelRaw)

#############################################################1 EDA of the data#######################################################

library(DataExplorer)
##introduce(LoanModelRaw)
plot_intro(LoanModelRaw)
plot_missing(LoanModelRaw)
##plot_bar(LoanModelRaw)
plot_histogram(LoanModelRaw)
create_report(LoanModelRaw)

?plot_boxplot

#Missing Value Treatment
library(mice)
sum(is.na(LoanModelRaw))
md.pattern(LoanModelRaw)
LoanModelRawImpute = mice(LoanModelRaw, m =5, method = 'pmm', seed = 1000)
LoanModelRawNoNa = complete(LoanModelRawImpute, 3)
md.pattern(LoanModelRawNoNa)

#Correcting negative experience
LoanModel = abs(LoanModelRawNoNa[2:14])
attach(LoanModel)
#View(LoanModel)
#summary(LoanModel)
#nrow(LoanModel)
```

#

```
LoanModel$Split = sample.split(LoanModel$PersonalLoan, SplitRatio = 0.7)
View(LoanModel)
LoanModelTrainRaw = subset(LoanModel,LoanModel$Split == TRUE)
LoanModelTestRaw = subset(LoanModel,LoanModel$Split == FALSE)

#Installing the packages for the running random forest
install.packages("randomForest")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)
attach(LoanModelTrain)
str(LoanModelTrain)

#Need to exclude the split and move columns
LoanModelTrain = LoanModelTrainRaw[1:13]
LoanModelTest = LoanModelTestRaw[1:13]
LoanModelTrain = LoanModelTrain %>% select(IncomeInKMonth,Mortgage,ZIPCode,CCAvg,everything())
LoanModelTest = LoanModelTest %>% select(IncomeInKMonth,Mortgage,ZIPCode,CCAvg, everything())
head(LoanModelTrain)
head(LoanModelTest)

###Converting the data set to a factor variable in order to be read
#Train
fcol = c(5:13)
LoanModelTrain[,fcol] = lapply(LoanModelTrain[,fcol], factor)
str(LoanModelTrain)
nrow(LoanModelTrain)

#Test
fcol = c(5:13)
LoanModelTest[,fcol] = lapply(LoanModelTest[,fcol], factor)
str(LoanModelTest)

##Running the random forest
seed = 1000
set.seed(seed)
LoanModelTrainRF = randomForest(PersonalLoan ~ ., data = LoanModelTrain, ntree = 501, mtry = 10, nodesize = 10, importance = TRUE, do.trace = TRUE)
print(LoanModelTrainRF)
plot(LoanModelTrainRF)
importance(LoanModelTrainRF)
?randomForest

###Tuning the random Forest
set.seed(seed)
LoanModelTrain = LoanModelTrain %>% select(PersonalLoan,everything())
str(LoanModelTrain)
LoanModelTrainRFTuned = tuneRF(x = LoanModelTrain[,-c(1)], 
                               y = PersonalLoan,
                               mtryStart = 10,
                               stepFactor = 1.5,
                               improve = 0.001,
                               trace = TRUE,
                               plot = TRUE,
                               doBest = TRUE,
                               importance = TRUE)

###Running refined random forest
LoanModelTrainRefinedRF = randomForest(PersonalLoan ~ ., data = LoanModelTrain, ntree = 95, mtry = 10, nodesize = 10, importance = TRUE, do.trace = TRUE)
print(LoanModelTrainRefinedRF)
plot(LoanModelTrainRefinedRF)


###Adding the prediction columns and probability columns 
LoanModelTrain$Predict = predict(LoanModelTrainRefinedRF,data= LoanModelTrain, type = "class")
LoanModelTrain$Score = predict(LoanModelTrainRefinedRF,data= LoanModelTrain, type = "prob")
head(LoanModelTrain)

###Check the accuracy of the model
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)

caret::confusionMatrix(LoanModelTrain$PersonalLoan, LoanModelTrain$Predict)


###Run the model against the Test Data
str(LoanModelTest)
```

**  LoanModelTest$Predict =  predict(LoanModelTrainRefinedRF,data= LoanModelTest, type = "class")
  **  LoanModelTest$Score  =  predict(LoanModelTrainRefinedRF,data= LoanModelTest, type = "prob")

```
AgeInYears  ExperienceInYears   IncomeInKMonth  ZIPCode FamilyMembers   CCAvg   Education
25  1   49  91107   4   1.6 1
45  19  34  90089   3   1.5 1
39  15  11  94720   1   1.0 1
35  9   100 94112   1   2.7 2
35  8   45  91330   4   1.0 2
37  13  29  92121   4   0.4 2

Mortgage    PersonalLoan    SecuritiesAccount   CDAccount   Online  CreditCard  Split
0   0   1   0   0   0   FALSE
0   0   1   0   0   0   FALSE
0   0   0   0   0   0   TRUE
0   0   0   0   0   0   TRUE
0   0   0   0   0   1   TRUE
155 0   0   0   1   0   TRUE
```

Comment: Can you please add lines of code that generates your `LoanModel` data frame? That way, I and everyone else can just copy and paste your code and check precisely where the problem is. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have added the lines of code that generate the Loan Model, I keep it as LoanModelRaw until I sort out the issues and then store it as LoanModel. Apologies if my code is messy but I am new to R and the coding sphere.

Comment: I apologize, I was not precise enough. I meant something that I can run on my computer without needing your file. For example, `LoanModelRaw <- data.frame(AgeInYears = c(10, 15, 23, 25, 26, 26, 28, 33, 40, 45), ....)` instead of loading the excel file you have. I think the best way to this is to sample 10 rows from your real data, change this rows such that it does not contain any secret information, and post it here.

Comment: Can you also please add on which line the error occurs? Thank you!

Comment: The line which the error occurs is the denoted by ** and I have added seven rows of data  that are from the file. Please do let me know if this is too little data as I just rand the head() function

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error trying to predict a single outcome from a simple glm model. In the model I specified the outcome and predictors using the format "dataset$outcome", etc. In the "test" set (really just one row of observations, I named the columns "outcome" etc. If I remove the $s from the model and instead specify "data=dataset", then the error disapears. So perhaps it's an issue with how objects are being called.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you try to append a column vector of length 3500 to a matrix that has 1500 rows. Of course, this does not work because R does not automatically create `ǸA` for the empty rows (and that is a good thing).

Try to check the dimensions (number of rows and number of columns) of `LoanModelTest` and `LoanModelTrain`. Also, check the return dimensions of the `predict` functions.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is odd for me as I am not trying to make additional values or empty rows, I am just trying to run an algortihm of the Test dataset so that it can predict values. The dimensions of the dataset will be the same in terms of columns however they would differ when it comes to the rows as the Test will have less then the Train dataset. Anyway I can stop R from trying to add more rows?

Comment: Your second sentence describes the problem I pointed out. In fact, you pointed it out twice. Once in this comment on my answer, and in your question ("The Train dataset does have 3500 rows and the Test would have 1500 rows"). But I don't understand your first sentence, because you clearly append a new columns to `LoanModelTest` in the last two code lines.

Comment: Apologies if I have repeated myself, I do acknowledge that the issue is that there is a difference in rows with the two datasets which causes the problem. Do you have suggestions in which I can sort the error without having to have the same amount of rows in both datasets? Is there a way to allow to make NA values so that the predict() function can run or place an additional argument in the predict() function to run without an error? What would you suggest I do next?

Comment: There seems to be a missunderstanding. Of course, your train data set and test data set will have the same columns but not the same number of rows (refering to your first comment here). Which seems to be the problem. Anyway, I have commented on your question above.